# How to convert IPFS link into JSON?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ipfs, js-ipfs

So my friends are making an NFT contract and using IPFS to store the metadata.
I want to look at the JSON contained in that IPFS link generated so that I can display the metadata in a Bootstrap card.
When I use this code to call one of the surfaced contract functions:

```
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(nftaddress, NFT.abi, provider);
const nft = await tokenContract.tokenURI(1);
console.log("nft:", nft);
```

I get this output, so I can see the function call from the contract worked:

```
nft: ipfs://Qmchgm5...GLnGMk
```

But then when I try to turn that IPFS link into a JSON format (as I can see when I visit the link URL) this doesn't work and throws this error:

```
console.log('nft:', nft.json());
// TypeError: nft.json is not a function
```

Can someone explain why putting in the link into my browser can show the JSON, but trying to read it from the link cannot? I assume this is some basic functionality of IPFS, but I cannot find anything (that makes sense to me, total newbie) telling me about this functionality and how to READ an IPFS object in my code.

Thank you in advance!
-PhilosophOtter

Comment: Your `nft` variable just contains the ipfs endpoint. You need to use the js-ipfs module to fetch the contents at that endpoint. Ww'll need more information on what the JSON that you're trying to retrieve is.

Comment: just trying to retrieve the image, name, description, etc... the metadata that another person put into the IPFS data. I want to map through it and make bootstrap cards

Comment: Hi, just wanted to mention how helpful this Q and A was - because I search all over for this example - it is very rare. I could not find many other links that show this. I will respond with more links If I can get it working. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPDS CID is not an object but a reference to an asset stored on the IPFS network so for example if the IPFS hash was:
`bafybeidyp5tc6vfjsis7rziok4o6j6ckjajpug4wceavcyujm6bsiqqk4m`
You can access it using an IPFS gateway like Dweb so you can do something like this:
`https://bafybeidyp5tc6vfjsis7rziok4o6j6ckjajpug4wceavcyujm6bsiqqk4m.ipfs.dweb.link/`
So you can get the JSON like this:

```
const data = await fetch("https://bafybeidyp5tc6vfjsis7rziok4o6j6ckjajpug4wceavcyujm6bsiqqk4m.ipfs.dweb.link/")
const json = await data.json()
console.log(json)
```

You should also read [this](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/what-is-ipfs/)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!

Comment: @PhilosophOtter Did this help you?

Comment: The project ended up going in another direction and I didn't need to do this in the end. But I would still like to test it, I will get back to you once I figure out where in the project this even was and try to reproduce the errors and solution!